# How can I assign a long list/tuple of items to one value in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a long list of items that I am trying to assign to one value in a dictionary.

Here is my code:

```
TSE_debt = ('21','22','23','24','25','26','27','31','32','33','34','35','36','39','3A','51','52','53','54','55','56',
            '62','63','64','65','66','67','81','82','83','84','85','91','93','94','95','96')

my_dict = {
    {future for future in TSE_debt: 'hello'} }
```

Let's say I want to assign each of the strings in `TSE_debt` to the string `hello` - how can I achieve this?

Desired output:

```
{'21': 'hello', '22': 'hello', '23':'hello', ...}
```

Addendum:

```
TSE_equities = ('01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '0A', '11', '12', '13', '17')
TSE_debt = ('21','22','23','24','25','26','27','31','32','33','34','35','36','39','3A','51','52','53','54','55','56',
            '62','63','64','65','66','67','81','82','83','84','85','91','93','94','95','96')
TSE_entitlements = ('3F', 'BB')
TSE_futures = ('A1','A2','A6','A8','A9','AA','C1')
TSE_other = ('B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','BA')

SECURITY_TYPE_CODE_TO_INSTRUMENT_TYPE = {
    equity : InstrumentTypes.EQUITY for equity in TSE_equities, 
    debt : InstrumentTypes.DEBT for debt in TSE_debt, 
    entitlement : InstrumentTypes.ENTITLEMENTS for entitlement in TSE_entitlements, 
    future : InstrumentTypes.FUTURES for future in TSE_futures,
    other : InstrumentTypes.OTHER for other in TSE_other}
```

Comment: Could you show the desired output (even truncated)?

Comment: `my_dict = {'hello': TSE_debt}`…?!

Comment: See above, I've added the desired output

Comment: `my_dict = dict.fromkeys(TSE_debt, 'hello')`

Comment: As a comprehension: `my_dict = {k: 'hello' for k in TSE_debt}`

Comment: Sorry can you help with the last part too? When I try doing it with multiple items in the `dict` it doesn't seem to work

Comment: `{**dict.fromkeys(TSE_equities, EQUITY), **dict.fromkeys(..., ...), ...}`